# Как настроить Codecov c Gradle?

Tags: gradle, travis, jacoco

Проект на `Gradle` к которому подключен `Travis CI` и [Codecov](https://codecov.io/). Проблема в том что индикация покрытия `unknown` хотя тесты есть и `jacoco` подключен.  [Ссылка на репозиторий](https://github.com/triodjangopiter/account-manager-server).

Конфиг Travis CI `.travis.yml`

```
language: java
jdk:
  - oraclejdk8
sudo: false
services:
  - postgresql
before_script:
  - psql -c 'create database account_manager;' -U postgres
  - chmod a+x gradlew
after_success:
  - bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash)
script:
  - ./gradlew build
  - ./gradlew jacocoTestReport
```

В `build.gradle` jacocoTestReport так же есть и связана с плагином `jacoco`:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'idea'
    id 'jacoco'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '1.5.9.RELEASE'
}
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

group 'ru.pravvich'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/" }
}

sourceSets {
    main { java { srcDir 'main/java/' } }
    test { java { srcDir 'test/java/' } }
}

dependencies {
    ...
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.7'
}

bootRun {
    jvmArgs = ["-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8", "-Xmx2048m", "-Xms512m"]
}

// Generate code coverage reports ... run with jacoco
jacocoTestReport {
    additionalSourceDirs = files(sourceSets.main.allJava.srcDirs)
    reports {
        xml.enabled false
        csv.enabled false
    }
    executionData = files('build/jacoco/test.exec')
}

check.dependsOn jacocoTestReport
test { finalizedBy jacocoTestReport }
```

Я предполагал что `Codecov` не видит отчета `jacoco` и добавил папку `build` в репозиторий,но это не помогло.
Почему Codecov может не работать и как это поправить?